# Google Cloud Service rather static or create instance each time?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-authentication

To access Google Cloud, I am using GoogleCredentials from a private key file to create a Service object. Below an example for BigQuery.

```
    GoogleCredentials credentials;
    File credentialsPath = new File(CONFIGURATION_FILENAME);
    try (FileInputStream serviceAccountStream = new FileInputStream(credentialsPath)) {
        credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccountStream);
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        // TODO manage exception handling
    }

    BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();
```

When I run this on App Engine, I just `.getDefaultInstance().getService()`, but when running somewhere else, I would need to read the configuration file each time I want to access, which will create IO overhead.

I assume I'd keep the `GoogleCredentials` static and only instantiate the service every time I need it, or should I keep the service static as well?

What are best practices here?

Comment: Why don't you always set the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` and always use `.getDefaultInstance().getService()`? That way it's consistent. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials

Comment: @GrahamPolley My file is inside the jar (as resource) which is distributed to different machines. There is no installer. Is there an advantage to using .getDefaultInstance().getService() except for having the private key outside the repository?

Comment: I probably wouldn't be shipping your key around in a jar file anyway. Best to keep them seperate. In our case we have our jar/binary, and the the key is pulled from a private GCS bucket and the env var is set before execution. We also use Docker which simplifies all this.

Comment: I do understand having a private key in the Git repository is not best practice. But I can't see how storing the key in a private bucket helps to protect it, apart from making it more difficult to be obtained. Credentials to the private bucket and the code which sets the env var is part of the repository, so whoever has access to the repository can access the key in the private bucket as well. IMHO, the only way to properly protect a production key would be injecting it into the container during build. Can you say a bit more about your Docker workflow, please.